# Terraform apply changes .kubeconfig?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I have a k8s cluster with application database and one fastapi application deployed to Digital Ocean. I am using terraform to create and modify my resources.
I have noticed that always I run terraform plan or apply besides changes to the configuration, it sometimes changes the .kubeconfig
The output of terraform plan shows something like that:

```
Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan:

  # module.kubernetes_cluster.digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.kubernetes_cluster has changed
  ~ resource "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "kubernetes_cluster" {
        id                   = "<cluster_id>"
      ~ kube_config          = (sensitive value)
        name                 = "<cluster-name>"
        tags                 = [
            "<tag>",
        ]
        # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

and after that changes to resources.

I have compared the .kubeconfig before and after `terraform apply` command and it changed an admin user token and a cluster server.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: no-change
    server: change!
  name: no-change
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: no-change
    user: no-change
  name: no-change
current-context:  no-change
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: no-change
  user:
    token: change!
```

Is it normal that does two values are changing? When it can happen? Does every time this happen all context locally and on the repository pipelines need to be updated?

Comment: This is because the tokens are temporary and have to be renewed so you can access the cluster. The server however I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 0):

Is it normal? Yes I think so.

Likely Digital Ocean uses ephemeral tokens and therefore that would be
normal.

The key is to call the auth endpoint to get a new token every time you want to connect to the cluster.

see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/ for the various auth methods.

The digital ocean docs tell you how to get a token here:
https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/kubernetes/how-to/connect-to-cluster/

and it comes down to:

```bash
doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save use_your_cluster_name
```